# Find nearest row that matches condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table with unique IDs, a date of service for a health care encounter, and whether this encounter was an emergency room visit (ed = 1) or a hospital admission (hosp = 1).

For each unique ID, I want to identify ED visits that occurred <= 1 calendar day from a hospital stay.

Thus I think I want to ask SQL first identify ED visits and then search up and down to find the nearest hospital admission and calculate the difference in dates (absolute value). I'm familiar with lag/lead and rownumber() functions, but can't quite seem to figure this out.

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Table looks like this for one illustrative ID:

```
id     date          ed  hosp       
1      2012-01-01    0   1      
1      2012-01-05    1   0
1      2012-02-01    0   1 
1      2012-02-03    1   0  
1      2012-05-01    0   0
```

And I want to create a new column (ed_hosp_diff) that is the minimum absolute date difference (days) between each ED visit and the closest hospital stay, something like this:

```
id     date          ed  hosp  ed_hosp_diff     
1      2012-01-01    0   1     null 
1      2012-01-05    1   0     4
1      2012-02-01    0   1     null
1      2012-02-03    1   0     2
1      2012-05-01    0   0     null
```

Comment: All of your iDs are 1, so your logic is not clear in your example.  I think you want the difference in days where the ED visit and the hosp visit have the same id, and the hosp visit is after the ed visit. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct! I should have added 2 unique IDs to my example to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this doesn't get you the output table you show, but it meets the requirement you list:

> For each unique ID, I want to identify ED visits that occurred <= 1
>   calendar day from a hospital stay.

Your output table doesn't really give you that - it includes rows for ED Visits that don't have a matching hospital admit, and has rows for hospital admits, etc.  This SQL doesn't give you those, it just gives you the ED Visits that were followed by a hospital admit within one day.

It also doesn't give you matches with negative days - cases where the hospital visit is prior to the ED visit (in terms of healthcare analytics, that's usually a different thing than looking for ED Visits followed by an IP Admit). If you do want those, delete the last bit of logic in the WHERE clause for the main query.

```
SELECT
    ID              =   e.id,
    ED_DATE         =   e.date,
    HOSP_DATE       =   h.date
    ED_HOSP_DIFF    =   DATEDIFF(dd, e.date, h.date)    
FROM 
    Table1 AS e
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        id,
        date
    FROM
        Table1
    WHERE
        hosp = 1
    ) AS h
ON
    e.id = h.id
WHERE
    e.ed = 1
AND
    DATEDIFF(dd, e.date, h.date) <= 1
AND 
    DATEDIFF(dd, e.date, h.date) >= 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! And I was able to easily flip the logic to identify ED visits that were >1 days apart from a hospital stay.

Answer (score -1):

use `OUTER APPLY` to get the record with ed = 1 and find the min date diff

```
SELECT *
FROM  table t
      OUTER APPLY
      (
          SELECT ed_hosp_diff = MIN ( ABS ( DATEDIFF(DAY, t.date, x.date) ) )
          FROM   table x
          WHERE  x.date <> t.date
          AND    x.ed = 1
      ) eh
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This looked nice and simple, but I kept getting an error related to having more than 1 column referenced in an aggregate column used in an outer reference...something like that. I'm sure it was my error as I'm still new to SQL.